# google search bar twitter-bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to create a plain index page with a Google-style centred search bar, however I'm struggling to get things looking good with Twitter Bootstrap.

The search bar must have a search icon button appended at the end (right side) of the search field. I have used typeahead as I am planning to code a dropdown search-suggestion system.

```html
<div class="hero-unit">
<div class="input-append">
  <input type="text" data-provider="typeahead" class="input-large"
  placeholder="What do you want to know?" autocomplete="off">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-large btn-success">
    <i class="icon-search"></i> 
  </button>
</div>
```

It must also be larger (taller) than the standard textbox, a feature not yet available in the stable release of Twitter Bootstrap, hence the CSS I have had to put at the top of the page.

```css
<style>
 input[class=input-large] {
    width: 540px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 11px 19px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
       -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
  }
```

The only way I could see of getting the search button closer to the searchbar (a gap appears when you use btn-large) was to use a negative margin. Not something I am proud of, it looks very messy.

I'd appreciate some guidance on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using `input-append` and `add-on`; they literally make the button and bar merge into one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <form>
        <div class='span3 input-append' style="margin-top:30%; margin-left:30%">
            <input class="span2" style="height:26px;width:400px;" id="main_search" type="text" >
            <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary"  type="button" value="search">
        </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle-

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/azF8w/14/)

Comment: Don't use `/>` in HTML5 for self-closing elements; it's not valid, and creates a void element. it's also invalid in HTML4 :)

Comment: you can just use `<input class="blah">` like the bootstrap docs do

Comment: This works and looks perfect, however I need to increase the height of the textbox and size of the button and this is what breaks everything. Getting append to work with standard size boxes/buttons is easy-peasy, it works out of the box. I do appreciate the effort though.

Comment: @Manoz Perfect! That style tag got things aligned perfectly.

Comment: @Manzon One more thing and the prize is yours: how do I go about setting the textfield to centre align and resize dependant on screen resolution rather than being fixed width? I'm sure it's pretty easy, I'm just pretty rusty!

Comment: <div class="input-append">
      <input class="input-large" id="searchfield" style="height:34px;width:200%;font-size:17.5px;"
      type="text">
      <button class="btn btn-large" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>

Comment: Updated fiddle now, please go through it for your answer.

Comment: It appears it is aligning by the textbox only, and is therefore offset by the adjoined button despite them both being wrapped in the div. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/WHHGy/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [extended form controls](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

```
<div class="input-append">
    <span class="add-on"><input id="search-button" value="Search"></span>
    <!-- stick a search icon in there instead -->
    <input class="span2" id="search">
</div>
```

You will have to adjust the CSS of the button if you do this (padding, outlines), though, but they will stay as one unit in a mobile view. If you really wanted a custom view, you'd have lowered the margins anyway.

Comment: Again, this doesn't help with the main issue - btn-large and bigger/taller textboxes. I must have missed the extended control bit in the docs though, so thanks for the reference.