# How to create responsive input and button using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to create responsive input and button like on that image:
[image]

Here is the similar question but it is not responsive: 
[google search bar twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528185/google-search-bar-twitter-bootstrap)

How to make it responsive?

I am using the latest bootstraper version.

Comment: Which version of BS you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of placing the controls over *two* rows so they collapse under each other, along with Bootstrap's [`text-center` helper class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-emphasis) to centre them (You can also use `offset` here too)

Lastly Bootstrap's input tags by default stretch to full-width of it's encased column, thus added a custom class to restrict the "search-input" to a user-setting width.

#### HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
    .smaller-input {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group smaller-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                  </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn btn-default">Google Search</div>
                <div class="btn btn-default">I'm Feeling Lucky</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A9C6U/

Comment: for some reason in my case it is a bit not exactly in the center, it has `padding-left: 15px;` should I increase it manually?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Re-adjust the `col-md-10` to `col-md-12` or `col-md-10` with `col-md-10 col-md-offset-2`, that'll take the full width, although I think you're asking about the `padding-left: 15px` on the .container?

Comment: I was saying about the padding on `<div class="col-md-10 text-center">` but now all good. I also changed the button `div` `class` to `col-md-12` so now looks like all centered perfectly

Comment: is there any way to make input `width` smaller but keep it in the centered?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Editted my answer to better suit, change the `.smaller-input` class to which ever size suits you =)

Answer (score 0):

put them in a grid tag will be responsive automatically.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        your html (button/input) here
     </div>
</div>
```

note: **don't assign fix size** to your inputs . e.g. width:300px

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: how to keep it on the center of the screen?